# Unable to delete a managed account via Stripe API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm trying to delete a managed account on Stripe using the following code, as specified in [Stripe's ruby docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api#delete_account):

```
a = Stripe::Account.retrieve(account_id)
a.delete
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `delete' for #<Stripe::Account:...>):
```

I'm using 1.23.0 of the official 'stripe' gem... seems like it could be a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `delete` was added [just recently](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/commit/af66e5ea353cf5bab115c56e52d6673cb5c93bc1)

Try updating your gem or specifying the GitHub repo in your Gemfile.

Comment: Yup, good catch. Pointing at github did the trick – which I guess means the code.stripe.com source is out of date?

Comment: They just haven't pushed a [release](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/releases) since that fix